# Find out if MPMoviePlayerController is currently playing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have one small problem regarding MPMoviePlayerController, i have a link that play movie when i click on that movie  button, however when i click on another button the application gets crashed, i need to find how to identify that movie is playing or getting any kind of response

Comment: Code and/or crash logs would help.

Comment: ok let me change the question i have movie running on iPhone simulator, i need to find in another function that wheater movie is playing or not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To expand on @Saurabh's answer you can check if the video is playing by

```
if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
{
// is Playing
}
```

where `MPMoviePlaybackState` is defined as

```
enum {
   MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward
};
typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;
```

Comment: In Swift to access the enumeration mentioned above use MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing - see my complete answer below.

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts, usually used in combination;

Register for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` e.g. like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

Within the notification handler, you may then check in detail for the actual state - e.g. like this:

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  //are we currently playing?
  if (movieController_.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
  { //yes->do something as we are playing...
  }
  else 
  { //nope->do something else since we are not playing
  }
}
```

You can certainly also use the playbackState property without handling the notification that signals changes of it. Still, in most cases that is the right place to do so.

When removing/killing your movie-playback, do not forget to remove the notification handler, e.g. like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `playbackState` property of MPMoviePlayerController. Refer this link -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

In swift the way to implement @ZKV7's answer is:

```
if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing)
{
  // is Playing
}
```

where the `MPMoviePlaybackState` enum is:

```
enum MPMoviePlaybackState : Int {
   case Stopped
   case Playing
   case Paused
   case Interrupted
   case SeekingForward
   case SeekingBackward
}
```

See [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMoviePlaybackState) for more information about the MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 0):

**to check video player is in playing state or not in SWIFT**

```
@IBAction func btnPressPlay(sender: AnyObject) {
        if videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing
        {
            self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.stop()
        }
        else {
            self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.play()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AVPlayerTimeControlStatus) {
    AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPaused,
    AVPlayerTimeControlStatusWaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate,
    AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0);


if(self.player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying)
{
  // is Playing
}
```