# How to detect MPMoviePlayerController starts a movie?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter, seek, nsnotification

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController`, how do I detect when the movie actually started playing - as opposed to when the user fiddles with the seek controls?

From the tests I made, I always get a "load state change" event and `(moviePlayer.loadState == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable)` is `TRUE` whenever the movie starts AND after the user dragged the seek control (even if he dragged it from end to middle - not necessarily to the beginning of the movie). How do I distinguish between movie-start and seek?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMoviePlaybackState) helps?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787394/find-out-if-mpmovieplayercontroller-is-currently-playing

Answer (score 28):

```
    MPMoviePlaybackState
    Constants describing the current playback state of the movie player.
    enum {
       MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
       MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
       MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
       MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
       MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
       MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward
    };
    typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;
```

Register for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

Check in this function MPMoviePlaybackState

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
      if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
      { //playing
      }
      if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
      { //stopped
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
      { //paused
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
      { //interrupted
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
      { //seeking forward
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward)
      { //seeking backward
      }

}
```

Remove notification by

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Refer :[MPMoviePlaybackState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMoviePlaybackState)

Comment: this also detects resume from a pause state - not just when the movie actually starts.

Answer (score 1):

**For swift**

**Add observer**

```
let defaultCenter: NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

**Function**

```
func moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        let moviePlayerController = notification.object as! MPMoviePlayerController

        var playbackState: String = "Unknown"
        switch moviePlayerController.playbackState {
        case .Stopped:
            playbackState = "Stopped"
        case .Playing:
            playbackState = "Playing"
        case .Paused:
            playbackState = "Paused"
        case .Interrupted:
            playbackState = "Interrupted"
        case .SeekingForward:
            playbackState = "Seeking Forward"
        case .SeekingBackward:
            playbackState = "Seeking Backward"
        }

        print("Playback State: %@", playbackState)
    }
```

Comment: I am getting .Playing state before it is actually starts playing. Is there anyway we can handle it?